# How to install ruamel.yaml on a buildroot environment

Tags: ruamel.yaml

`ruamel.yaml` seems to require PIP to install, which is not the default buildroot solution to build and install a Python package.

1. Is is possible to -at least- install a pure Python version of `ruamel.yaml` into a buildroot image - and how to circumvent the pip limitation?
2. Is is possible to cross-build `ruamel.yaml`?

Forcing `RUAMEL_NO_PIP_INSTALL_CHECK` env. var. does not help:

```
test compiling test_ruamel_yaml
running install
Checking .pth file support in ...
Failed to import the site module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m_linux_arm-linux-gnueabihf'
error: command '.../output/host/bin/python' failed with exit status 1
package/pkg-generic.mk:310: recipe for target '.../output/build/python-ruamel-yaml-0.15.45/.stamp_target_installed' failed
```

Answer (score 1):

`ruamel.yaml` indeed requires `pip` to install from PyPI (using the `.tar.gz` or a `.whl` appropriate for your platform), this is [documented](http://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html).

The reason for this is that the fixes necessary to enable nested package installs where only implemented for `pip` (and not for `easy_install` or `python setup.py` installs).

That however does not preclude you from using `ruamel.yaml`, especially if you don't need the `C` extension (which is checked for at load time).

You can either check out a tagged version from bitbucket or untar a `.tar.gz` from PyPI and move the result to your site-packages directory:

```
$ virtualenv /tmp/ruamel_yaml_no_pip
Using base prefix '/opt/python/3.7'
New python executable in /tmp/ruamel_yaml_no_pip/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
$ cd /tmp/ruamel_yaml_no_pip/
$ source bin/activate
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ mkdir lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ touch lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/__init__.py 
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ wget -q https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/a5/dba37230d6cf51f4cc19a486faf0f06871d9e87d25df0171b3225d20fc68/ruamel.yaml-0.15.45.tar.gz
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ python -m ruamel.yaml
/tmp/ruamel_yaml_no_pip/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'ruamel.yaml' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ruamel')
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ tar xf ruamel.yaml-0.15.45.tar.gz 
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ mv ruamel.yaml-0.15.45 lib/python3.7/site-packages/ruamel/yaml
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ python -c 'from ruamel.yaml import YAML; print(YAML().load("{hello: world}")["hello"])'
world
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip)
(ruamel_yaml_no_pip) $ python -c 'from ruamel.yaml import __with_libyaml__ as X; print(X)'
False
```

(The URL is copied from the [0.15.45 project download page](https://pypi.org/project/ruamel.yaml/0.15.45/#files))

For development I normally just make a soft link from a virtualenv's site-packages to my `ruamel` directory.

I don't know how and if that translates to a `buildroot` environment (if so please publish your result).

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the buildroot documentation.

There is a critical parameter to define: `SETUP_TYPE = setuptools` rather than `SETUP_TYPE = distutils`.

With the following snippet:

```
PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_VERSION = 0.15.45
PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_SOURCE = ruamel.yaml-$(PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_VERSION).tar.gz
PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_SITE = https://pypi.python.org/packages/63/a5/dba37230d6cf51f4cc19a486faf0f06871d9e87d25df0171b3225d20fc68
PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_SETUP_TYPE = setuptools
PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_LICENSE = MIT
PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_LICENSE_FILES = LICENSE

PYTHON_RUAMEL_YAML_ENV += RUAMEL_NO_PIP_INSTALL_CHECK=1

$(eval $(python-package))
```

`ruamel.yaml` installs perfectly on the target image.